# Split a column into separate columns based on value

Tags: bash, unix

I have a tab delimited file that looks as follows:

```
cat my file.txt
```

gives:

```
    1   299
    1   150
    1   50
    1   57
    2   -45
    2   62
    3   515
    3   215
    3   -315
    3   -35
    3   3
    3   6789
    3   34
    5   66
    5   1334
    5   123
```

I'd like to use Unix commands to get a tab-delimited file that based on values in column#1, each column of the output file will hold all relevant values of column#2
(I'm using here for the example the separator "|" instead of tab only to illustrate my desired output file):

```
299   |   -45   |   515   |   66
150   |   62    |   215   |   1334
50    |         |   -315  |
57    |         |   -35   |
      |         |    3    |
```

The corresponding Headers (1,2,3,5;  based on column#1 values) could be a nice addition to the code (as shown below), but the main request is to split the information of the first file into separated columns. Thanks!

```
1     |    2    |   3     |   5       
299   |   -45   |   515   |   66
150   |   62    |   215   |   1334
50    |         |   -315  |
57    |         |   -35   |
      |         |    3    |
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gnu-awk`

```
awk '
BEGIN{max=0;}
{
    d[$1][length(d[$1])+1] = $2;
    if(length(d[$1])>max) 
        max = length(d[$1]);
}
END{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";
    line = "";
    flag = 0;
    for(j in d){
        line = line (flag?"\t|\t":"") j;
        flag = 1;
    }
    print line;
    for(i=1; i<=max; ++i){ 
        line = "";
        flag = 0;
        for(j in d){
            line = line (flag?"\t|\t":"") d[j][i];
            flag = 1;
        } 
        print line;
    }
}' file.txt
```

you get

```
1   |   2   |   3   |   5
299 |   -45 |   515 |   66
150 |   62  |   215 |   1334
50  |       |   -315    |   
57  |       |   -35 |   
    |       |   3   |
```

Or, you can use `python` .... for example, in `split2Columns.py`

```
import sys
records = [line.split() for line in open(sys.argv[1])]
import collections
records_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, val in records:
    records_dict[key].append(val)

from itertools import izip_longest
print "\t|\t".join(records_dict.keys())
print "\n".join(("\t|\t".join(map(str,l)) for l in izip_longest(*records_dict.values(), fillvalue="")))
```

```
python split2Columns.py file.txt
```

you get same result

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner that matches your output. It builds a string `$ARGS` containing as many process substitutions as there are unique values in the first column. Then, `$ARGS` is used as the argument for the `paste` command:

```
HEADERS=$(cut -f 1 file.txt | sort -n | uniq); ARGS=""; for h in $HEADERS; do ARGS+=" <(grep ^"$h"$'\t' file.txt | cut -f 2)"; done; echo $HEADERS | tr ' ' '|'; eval "paste -d '|' $ARGS"
```

Output:

```
1|2|3|5
299|-45|515|66
150|62|215|1334
50||-315|
57||-35|
||3|
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jose Ricardo Bustos M. - thanks for your answer! I unfortunately couldn't install on my Mac the gnu-awk, but based on your suggestive answer I've performed something similar using awk:

```
HEADERS=$(cut -f 1 try.txt | awk '!x[$0]++');
H=( ${HEADERS// / });
MAXUNIQNUM=$(cut -f 1 try.txt |uniq -c|awk '{print $1}'|sort -nr|head -1); 
awk -v header="${H[*]}" -v max=$MAXUNIQNUM 
'BEGIN {
       split(header,headerlist," ");
       for (q = 1;q <= length(headerlist); q++)
           {counter[q]=1;}
 }
{for (z = 1; z <= length(headerlist); z++){
     if (headerlist[z] == $1){
        arr[counter[z],headerlist[z]] = $2; 
        counter[z]++
        };
     } 
 } 
 END { 
     for (x = 1; x <= max; x++){ 
         for (y = 1; y<= length(headerlist); y++){ 
              printf "%s\t",arr[x,headerlist[y]];
              } 
         printf "\n"
         }
     }' try.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is using an array to keep track of the column headings, using them to name temporary files and `paste` everything together in the end:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile=$1
filenames=()
idx=0

while read -r key value; do
   if [[ "${filenames[$idx]}" != "$key" ]]; then
       (( ++idx ))
       filenames[$idx]="$key"
       echo -e "$key\n----" > "$key"
   fi
   echo "$value" >> "$key"
done < "$1"

paste "${filenames[@]}"

rm "${filenames[@]}"
```